# Did contemporaries refer to the liberation of Yugoslavia in 1945 as a liberation?

Tags: world-war-two, political-history, yugoslavia

Tito of Yugoslavia, with help from the Russians, expelled Wehrmacht troops from Belgrade in 1944, establishing himself as sole dictator with virtually no political opposition that wasn't in prison or a concentration camp. Was that situation still seen as a liberation from the viewpoint of the citizens of Yugoslavia at the time?

Comment: I don't understand what "Liberation in historical sense" means. Do you perhaps mean to ask whether contemporary commentators refer to it as a liberation?

Comment: If you're the one doing the liberating, you are freeing the land from the naughty clutches of your enemy. Maybe it's the Marxists who gave it a people-centric meaning. Anyway this seems more to do with language than history.

Comment: History is defined by the victors and liberation by the liberators.  I'm not aware of a definition for "liberation", so whoever is doing the liberation gets to pick the definition.

Comment: Who "we"? The difference between "liberation" and "conquest" depends on the political views of a person who is speaking. Both the Germans and the Soviets called their conquests liberation.

Comment: This question is more a philosophical question than a history question because it all comes down to what is the meaning of liberation. Different people and different groups can and have applied different meanings to the term for their own purposes. From one perspective, yes, Tito did liberate Yugoslavia from the clutches of the Wehrmacht but Yugoslavia was not a truly liberated country when the communist government took control. A similar question could be asked about the German Democratic Republic (former East Germany). Was it really a democracy?

Comment: @Fred introduces an important new concept - "liberated" as related to "liberal". Without getting en-mired in modern language "liberal state" means a state with a legal/constitutional respect for the individual.

Comment: @Fred  Tito and his movement was strategically insignificant. Outcome of the war was decided on the steppes of  Russia and sky of Western Europe. IMHO if the Hitler won the war he could easily wipe Tito's forces,  not big deal for him. Tito could even try to accommodate himself with Hitler as he already showed that during "March Negotiations 1943" with Germans.

Comment: @Semaphore - Exactly that..

Comment: `"Liberation" from the viewpoint of then citizen of Yugoslavia?` May I ask one question, please? Considering the opinion of contemporaries of Jeanne d'Arc, how should we call her now: liberator or witch?

Comment: @Matt How's that relevant? If someone asked what Jeanne was called by her contemporaries it would be a valid question too.

Comment: The answer to this question is simple: yes. There were no major insurgencies or rebellions after 1944 and Tito's rule is generally seen in a positive light. After Yugoslavia broke up the different nations went their own way but still genrally few the Tito period positively, and certainly better than the National Socialist occupation.

Comment: @Mustang What about Cazin rebellion? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cazin_rebellion ? I do not say that whole reign of Tito was 100 % negative, let that be clear, but still he was ruthless dictator in start of his reign. Somebody could argue that Hitler had something  positive in his historical figure,  because after he started his reign Germany rebuild her economy, first highways  were made under his rule, but we all know his place in history.

Comment: Interesting. I did not know that. I really have no idea how Yugoslavs perceived 1945 and the people who could answer that question are mostly dead.

Comment: There is no doubt that Tito's forces and the Soviets liberated the country from Nazi occupation and rule.  Questions about how matters developed after that are not at all relevant to the issue.

Comment: @Semaphore I only want to say that even an ultraconservative monarchist possibly suffering of mental disorder may be perfectly legally depicted as both liberator and icon of democracy. And whether or not some contemporaries thought him (or her) a satanist, a tyrant etc. absolutely doesn't matter.

Comment: @Matt Except if what contemporaries thought was the question....

Comment: @RISwampYankee "Was that situation still seen as a liberation from the viewpoint of the citizens of Yugoslavia at the time?" Maybe it's my lack of knowledge of English language specifics - but historical events can be judged also by the people who were born after  some historical event happened ?